# Is there an easier way to make enum constants visible?

Tags: enums, rust

I find myself writing stuff like this:

```rs
pub enum Player {BLACK, WHITE,}

const BLACK: Player = Player::BLACK;
const WHITE: Player = Player::WHITE;
```

The reason, of course, being to avoid noise in match expressions and other uses of the constants.

Is there an easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just import the enum variants with the `use` keyword.

```rust
pub enum Player {
    Black,
    White,
}

use Player::*;
```

Comment: Indeed, this does it! The funny thing is, I already did this from another module, but didn't dare to try it from within the same module.

Comment: Naturally you can also do `pub use Player::*;` and export the enum variants, same as `Some`, `None`, `Ok`, `Err`...