# Is there a way to stop repeating an enum's name when I want to refer to its variants?

Tags: syntax, enums, rust, reference

In Rust you don't need to refer to `Option::Some` and `Option::None`, you can just refer directly to `Some` and `None` in your code.

Is there a way that you can do this for new enums you create, so that instead of always writing `MyEnum::OptionOne` you can just write `OptionOne`?

Comment: Duplicate of [is there an easier way to make enum constants visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266286/is-there-an-easier-way-to-make-enum-constants-visible)

Comment: @Herohtar Hah. I had looked for another question and couldn't find one, and then it turns out it was asked only one day prior!

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite simple, you just add a `use` statement after defining the enum:

```
pub enum MyEnum {
    OptionOne,
    OptionTwo,
    OptionThree,
}
use MyEnum::*;
```

Other code in the same file can now refer to `OptionOne` etc, rather than having to write `MyEnum::OptionOne`.

Comment: May be worth mentioning: if you want users of your module to be able to do the same, you would write `pub use MyEnum::*;` instead.